# How to fetch data from row that is indexed to another table row?

Tags: mysql

Hi I have mysql table like that:

```
.poll_users
(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (id))

.poll_referendum
        (id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
        name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY (id))

.poll_questions 
     id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    referendum_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    body varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    created_at datetime DEFAULT NULL
    updated_at datetime DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    KEY `referendum_id` (`referendum_id`))

.poll_answers 
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
 `vote_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0'
 `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL
 `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
 `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 KEY `vote_id` (`vote_id`)
 KEY `question_id` (`question_id`))

.poll_voting 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    `answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    KEY `question_id` (`question_id`)
    KEY `answer_id` (`answer_id`)
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`))

.vote_types 
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

How can I fetch vote types that are in vote_types table and correspond to proper question and survey?

I have tried: `SELECT vote_id FROM surveys.poll_answers WHERE question_id = 1;`
but this gives me: 
[image]

and  1,2 are indexes to the vote type text `SELECT *
FROM`surveys`.`vote_types
`WHERE`id`=1`
In poll_answers table I keep indexes what vote types are assigned to questions and questions are assigned to proper referendums in poll_referendum table
so how do I fetch those vote types corresponing to proper question and survey
like

```
SELECT vote_id indexes from poll_answers table and they index to vote_types where are stored vote types in text and those vote_types corresponds to proper questions that are stored in poll_questions and referendums that are stored in poll_referendum ?
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Perhaps you are talking about table joins.

```
SELECT 
           v.*
      FROM poll_answers AS a
      INNER JOIN poll_voting AS v ON (v.id=a.vote_id)
      WHERE a.question_id = 1;
```